# Nextjs 13 routing based on fetched data

Tags: next.js

I would like to build a wizard in nextjs and have the following folder structure

[wizardUuid] folder that has 4 subfolders in it [step1, step2, step3, step4]

When someone click on a wizard, I would like to direct them to the correct step based of the data fetched from the [wizardUuid]layout.js

I would like to fetch the data server side and handle the routing from there!

What would be the best approach

I tried solving it with middleware and in layouts with no success

Answer (score 0):

You can do this within the `app dir` layouts, but you will need to use a dynamic path, i.e. [step].jsx file in the folder route. Next will return value you gave it from the url and from there you can use the step prop to figure out which step they are on.

Here is the Next documentation on what you are looking for:
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes